# Why does this VirtualBox disk not dynamically expand?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have a vagrant configured VirtualBox VM running Ubuntu 14.04. Whenever doing a major mysql import within the box, I notice that the import was incomplete.  If I try to restart mysql, this error occurs:

```
[FAIL] /etc/init.d/mysql: ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full! ... failed!
```

I resized the VMDK image by cloning to VDI, resizing, and cloning back to VMDK as I had read this might fix the problem.

```
$ df -h
rootfs                               9.1G  8.7G  8.0K 100% /
```

I'm aware that the `/tmp` filesystem is mounted separately in Ubuntu, so I even tried changing the tmp directory on mysql.ini and that didn't work either.

```
$ VBoxManage showhdinfo <guid>
Parent UUID:    base
State:          created
Type:           normal (base)
Storage format: VMDK
Format variant: dynamic default
Capacity:       24000 MBytes
Size on disk:   6894 MBytes
```

Comment: I have a similar problem. I'm experimenting with large Subversion repository dump/restore and running out of space: `State: locked write; Type: normal (base); Storage format: VMDK; Format variant: dynamic default; Capacity: 10140 MBytes`